# What does it mean to inline a constant?

Tags: scala

I'm reading this [article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/03/akka-best-practices-defining-actor-props/) and there is this piece of code:

```
object ChildActor {

  final val Name = "child-actor"

  def apply(value: Int): Props = Props(new ChildActor(value))
}
```

and a note:

> When defining constants final and starting with an upper case letter,
>   the Scala compiler will inline them.

I don't get it. I know about method inlining, where a new stack frame is eliminated for the method call. But what does it mean for compiler to inline a constant, could you clarify?

Comment: By the way: an upper case letter is not required. Read the spec about [constant value definitions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I am not familiar with scala per se, but the term "inline constant" means it will change the constant reference into a constant value, and directly hard-code the value of the constant to any reference at compile time. This eliminates the need for the additional memory space to keep the reference.

So, at compile time, the compiler changes the code such that

```
final val Name = "child-actor" 
val otherName = Name
```

is treated as

```
final val Name = "child-actor" 
val otherName = "child-actor"
```

Comment: sounds reasonable

Comment: Note the implication that if you recompile the file where Name is defined, but not the file where otherName is defined, otherName keeps the old value. This doesn't happen for non-inlined constants.

Comment: What's the benefit of inlining a constant?

Comment: @flow2k the variable becomes a constant at compile time, so the benefits are:
1) it would save memory space.
2) prevents other devs and/or methods from changing it accidentally. In some languages, changing an inline constant is a compile time error, in some of the loosely typed languages, it is a runtime error.