# Scala Inheritance - How declaring fields as final solve construction order problem

Tags: scala, inheritance

I am referring book "**Scala for the Impatient**" for learning purpose.  I found some example of construction order problem and solution of early definition.

The book has tried to showcase the problem with following class :

```
class Creature {
  val range: Int = 10
  val env: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](range)

}

class Ant extends Animal {
  override val range: Int = 2
}
```

Here, as per the construction order problem, while creating an instance of class `Ant`, the super class `Creature` constructor is called and the env array is initialised with default Int value zero.

To solve the problem, they have mentioned three possible solutions :

1. Declare the val as final
2. Declare val as lazy in super class
3. Use early definition syntax

It is easy to understand the **point#2** and **point#3** logically.

But how can we solve this problem by declaring the `range` field as `final` in sub class ?

I tried with following solution and it worked. But I am not able to logically relate here how overriding a `field` as `final` in subclass can solve this ?

```
package ed2 {

  class Creature {
    val range: Int = 10
    val env: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](range)
  }

  class Ant extends Creature {
    final override val range = 2
  }
}
```

**Note : One important point to note here is, we are able to produce this behaviour while deferring the type declaration of the final overridden field in subclass `final override val range = 2`. This code snippet returns zero if we declare field type in subclass.**

How the compiler treats `final` fields of subclass ? Does it gives first priority to final members for initialisation ?

Comment: I have tried to replicate the problem here : https://scastie.scala-lang.org/p5fXFRejQAW3RGcdvMjbPg

Comment: A simpler illustration of the issue here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/E6xL9zoxQcupcZguNtKEjg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book is correct but not completely. There is a type of expression in Scala called [Constant Value](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions). It is inlined everywhere it is used:

> The final modifier must be present and no type annotation may be given. References to the constant value x are themselves treated as constant expressions; in the generated code they are replaced by the definition's right-hand side e.

So in short,

1. It requires final keyword
2. It requires no type annotation

Then they are inlined in the class definition and therefore it is 2 in your Ant class.

In other cases where you supply a type definition like `final override val range: Int = 2`, then it is not considered a constant value and not inlined. Therefore it is initialized according to the regular order of inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I referred the "value constant" definition which you have shared. I tried by adding println statements in subclass and super class.  But, I am not able to understand how that constant value is getting reflected in super class before executing the statements in the subclass.

Comment: I tried by adding println statements to check the order of execution. Please refer the code here : https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Qp8xSFCxQzGM3A7XOxBVdw

Comment: I think, I need to better understand the meaning of Inline Constant here to understand how the value of constant is getting reflected in super class directly. I think, this question on stackoverflow is correct answer to solve my confusion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433828/what-does-it-mean-to-inline-a-constant#:~:text=Well%2C%20I%20am%20not%20familiar,space%20to%20keep%20the%20reference.

Comment: @GunjanShah The initialization order when a constant value is involved is mangled at bytecode level. val in Scala is actually compiled to a getter method + underlying member variable. When a constant value is involved, the getter method is overridden with returning a constant expression. In general you don't need to understand how it works underlying. It just works the way it is described.